# Google Or-tools compilation/build fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio, or-tools

I am trying to get Google Or-tools to work, I followed this tutorial to install it: https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/cpp/windows.

After running the `tools\make test.cc`, I created new C++ project, added includes of the library to `C/C++ additional includes`. When I try to build/run I got errors like these: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozVNL.png.

I have win7 64bit and MSVC 2019 so it is a bit different than theirs configuration but this does not seem to be connected.

- The identifier errors look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIe0T.png
- The error in optional_boolean looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsUuP.png

Does anybody knows what is happening? Does their code have errors or am I doing something wrong?

*(I also tried to compile directly from the source but bumped into different problems...)*

Comment: Next time I would appreciate that whoever downvoted the question would also provide reason why. I really want to know what I did wrong so I can make it right next time. Just drive-by downvote is completely useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. The problem was faulty distribution of google or-tools. At least the problem was with library used by or-tools while using MSVC - it can be some sort of mutual incompatibility, I really don't know, but still they couldn't have tested it and I don't understand how that can happen and get into release).

**Steps to solution were these:**

1. Grab this version of or-tools:
   https://github.com/google/or-tools/releases/tag/v6.10
2. Extract it where you wish to have it.

**A  If creating completely new project:**

3. Grab this (thanks to @Laurent): https://github.com/philippe3263/ORTools_Visual_Studio
4. Reconfigure `include path, lib path` and in `Linker->All Options` remove/delete `Additional Options`.

**B  If editing existing project:**

3. Set x64 debug profile.
4. add `include and lib paths`.
5. Add `ortools.lib` to extra libraries.
6. Add preprocessor directives `_WINDOWS NOMINMAX USE_CBC USE_CLP USE_BOP USE_GLOP`
7. It's possible that other settings are necessary like `C/C++ -> Code generation -> Runtime library to /MD` but since I already had a lot of custom settings I can't tell what is needed. *(but checking the link and going through those settings can help)*

*Tested on Win7 64bit with VS 2019*

Comment: 6.10 is very old. The routing and the CP-SAT libraries are far behind.

Comment: Sadly you are right, I was trying to get the VRP problem working but it's completely different than in the documentation since it's for version 7.3. Wouldn't you know by chance if there is some place with older documentation?

BTW I don't want to sound ungreatful I appreciate your help and the product itself but it would be good to provide accurate information about product support. I am not 100% certain but at this point I don't think that the statement that google or-tools works with VS2017 and Win10 on the webpage is correct.

Comment: I build and test it on vs2017 and win10.

Comment: The question is then why it does not work for me (I have win7 but besides that I tested everything and I highly doubt that OS version will have anything to do with it). From the errors provided in my original post I think it is not necessarily problem of or-tools code but rather the dependencies used so maybe you tested with other versions than those in binary release? (sorry if what I suggest is stupid, frankly I don't exactly understand how it works under the hood, but I just don't get where is the problem then)

Comment: @Laurent I tried to compile the source version from the website and installed it on my machine. It didn't work but then when I launched the project with 7.3 binary just because I wanted to give it one more try, it just worked. Sometimes when I compile the same errors flash in the output but it works. I have no clue what the problem is especially when 6.10 worked before with the same configuration project you sent and 7.3 did not. I am perplexed, maybe the source installation somehow solved it in the background? Anyways I apologise in case this is somehow fault of my setup.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the includes, but did you change the libraries to link with.

Anyway, you should have a look at:

https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1449

Comment: The problem was basically fault of or-tools. Thanks for the link it helped me in the right direction.